# Is this a bug in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm replicating a scenario from my application,

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' disabled='true' />
<input type='text' disabled='true' />
<input type='text' disabled='true' />
<input type='text' disabled='true' />
<div disabled='true'>
    <input type='text' disabled='true' />
</div>
<input type='text' disabled='true' />
<p id='test'></p>
```

I want to enable these elements on a button click, the equivalent js,

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var p = document.querySelector('#test');
[].slice.call(x);

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    p.innerHTML += x[i].getAttribute("disabled") + " ";

    x[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

Works fine in all browsers, 
but, in IE, the `input` with it's parent disabled, appears disabled, but isn't.

Any explanation as to why this is happening?

I do realize that `disabled` is not a valid property for a `div`, but IE should ignore such a property?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ6DP/1/)

Comment: I don't think attribute `disabled="true"` is available in div

Comment: Did you mean x = [].slice.call(x); ? Not that it would change the behavior of the loop, it's just that it has no effect when you don't assign the result.

Comment: In safari all are enabled. I wouldn't say this is a bug as div cannot have property disabled

Comment: @TepkenVannkorn Well, IE should bypass it then?

Comment: @AshleyMedway IE should bypass it as an invalid property?

Comment: Looks like the disabled is getting applied to the inner elements when it is on the IE div.

Comment: @jwize Not quite sure that's happening, as I'm able to change the values in the text box.

Comment: disabled is an attribute relative to the controls of a form and it's not set by true or false: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't conclude it is a bug but gives a little more insight into things.

http://www.techtamasha.com/the-disabled-attribute-in-internet-explorer/256

Directly from that article:

> ‘disabled’ attribute only works on BUTTON INPUT, OPTGROUP, OPTION,
>   SELECT, and TEXTAREA tags and the general policy of browser is if you
>   use any attribute which are not authorized to use in tag then browsers
>   neglect them but they can be accessed using javascript. But IE isn’t
>   that kind in this case. If you apply ‘disabled’ on div tag, IE takes
>   it seriously and makes div tag disabled. So what this means is that we
>   not only have any control event on div but also according to “This
>   attribute is inherited but local declarations override the inherited
>   value.” rule in W3C disable specification, IE applies disabled
>   attribute on nested elements in div tag. So be careful.